# How to get an array based list of directories in node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js

Let's say we have a directory that contains four folders, like so:

```
- folder-1
- folder-2
- folder-3
- folder-4
```

How can I get their path and store them in an array so I'd have an array like:

```
['root/parent/folder-1', 'root/parent/folder-2', 'root/parent/folder-3', 'root/parent/folder-4']
```

Comment: use the `path` module https://nodejs.org/api/path.html and please, tell us a bit more about the context, are you listing the current directory? Do you just happen to have an array of dir strings?

Comment: @cl3m Thanks, it may be the current directory and it may not, I don't have an array, I'm trying to create one based on directories name.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do it this way if you don't need absolute path omit `__dirname` use `dirPath`:

```
var fs = require('fs');

var dirPath = 'parent/';
var result = []; //this is going to contain paths

fs.readdir(__dirname + dirPath, function (err, filesPath) {
    if (err) throw err;
    result = filesPath.map(function (filePath) {
        return dirPath + filePath;
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You could do it through [`fs.readdir`](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_readdir_path_callback)

```
var fs = require('fs');

fs.readdir('root/parent/', function(err, files) {
    if (err)
        console.log(err);
    else
        files.map(function(f) {
            return 'root/parent/'+f;
        });
        return files;
})
```